# Integrate Interstitials Ads from Admob to Windows Phone 8 Monogame

Tags: xna, admob, monogame

Currently i develop game using XNA with Monogame Framework.
To monetize it, i use admob as an ads.

my question is, how to display Interstitials Ads in specific time. So interstitial ads view will be hidden and displayed when specific time occurred, such as game is over, etc. Because i prefer display ads when game already over and before score displayed, ads appear first.

please point me the way to do that.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't experimented yet with the Windows Phone 8 API for admob, but I use AdMob Interstitials in my Android games. I imagine the logic should be fairly similar, so I will post it here.

In my game class, I add a delegate that will fire a function to load the ads when I choose to do so

```cs
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    ...
    /// <summary>
    /// Event that fires popup ads during the game
    /// </summary>
    public Action OnLaunchAds;
    ...
}
```

Then, when I create the Android Activity, which in your case should be the program entry for windows phone (or whatever the lifecycle is), I have a function that is ready to create the ad at any moment. Should look something like this:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Creates the Interstitial ad that will popup when the game calls
/// for it
/// </summary>
private void createPopup()
{
    InterstitialAd popup = AdHelper.CreatePopup(this, POPUP_ID);

    var listener = new AdMobHelper.AdTrigger();
    listener.loadFunctions += () => { if (popup.IsLoaded) { popup.Show(); } };

    popup.AdListener = listener;

    try
    {
        /// Create the request
        AdRequest.Builder request = new AdRequest.Builder();

        /// Add test devices
        request.AddTestDevice(AdRequest.DeviceIdEmulator);
        request.AddTestDevice(TEST_DEVICE_ID);

        popup.LoadAd(request.Build());
    }
    catch (Exception e) { e.ToString(); }
}
```

From here its just a matter of assigning the delegate in your main Game to point to the function you just created, like so:

```cs
game.OnLaunchAds = createPopup;
```

That way, you can choose when to show the ad. I do it when the player has died 3 times in a row.

The only thing you might get hung up on is the line that says AdRequest.Builder request = new AdRequest.Builder(); because this is a custom class I made to implement the abstract class AdListener. It is not strictly necessary, but its purpose is to provide a way for the ad to first load, and then show when it is finished loading. It avoids "showing" an ad that hasn't loaded yet. If you need help with this too, I can post it here as well